# Call a javascript command in the UIWebView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to call a `javascript` command in the `UIWebView` page such as:

```
javascript:document.getElementById(\"MainContent_btnApprove\").click();
```

however I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
string url = "javascript:document.getElementById(\"MainContent_btnApprove\").click();";
WebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
WebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

But then I get a message saying:

> System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the web 'Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:' method returned nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ObjC `NSURL`'s selector `initWithString:` returns `nil` if the value is not a correct/valid URL (and that varies a bit between iOS versions). The exception you get is Xamarin.iOS telling you that iOS itself did not like the `url` value you provided.

From your description I think you're looking for something like:

```
WebView.EvaluateJavascript ("document.getElementById(\"MainContent_btnApprove\").click();");
```